# Make grid grow to fit text content?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I have a `Grid` in SwiftUI 5 (iOS 17) inside a widget.

```
Grid(horizontalSpacing: 4, verticalSpacing: 0) {
    ForEach(Array(dangerRatings.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, dangerRating in
        GridRow {
            Color("DangerLevel\(dangerRating.mainValue)")
                .frame(width: 12)
                .clipShape(
                    .rect(
                        topLeadingRadius: index == 0 ? 4 : 0,
                        bottomLeadingRadius: index == dangerRatings.count - 1 ? 4 : 0,
                        bottomTrailingRadius: index == dangerRatings.count - 1 ? 4 : 0,
                        topTrailingRadius: index == 0 ? 4 : 0
                    )
                )
            Text(dangerRating.mainValue).foregroundColor(Color("Text")).bold()
        }
        if index < dangerRatings.count - 1 {
            GridRow {
                Color("DangerLevel?").frame(width: 12, height: 3)
                Text("-2300m-").foregroundColor(Color("Text"))
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                //.frame(height: 3)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Text"))
                    .bold()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the text "-2300m-" is getting trimmed and put on multiple lines. But I want it to expand to be readable on a single line and have the grid expand to make it fit.

[image]
If I try to set a fixed frame width to the grid to make it fit the text, the other content of the widget ends up overflowing.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: try  something like this Text("Something").minimumScaleFactor(0.5).lineLimit(1)

Comment: I found ` .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)` to work in this case. Thanks for the help though.